# geolocation, share location dialog

Tags: javascript, html

If you want to know the users geolocation in a web browser you have to use the html 5 api. When calling the function:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success)
```

a dialog pops up, asking the user if he want to share the location or not. My question is, is it possible to know when the user clicked confirmed. I want to display a loading spinner on a html page after the user has clicked the confirm button. (To get the location can take some time on a mobile, and i don't want the spinner to show before he has pressed the confirm button, as he can get confused )

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this code? You can add Callback functions, and within them handle user responses.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback {maximumAge:600000});

function successCallback(position) {
    // Handle Confirm button hit
}

function errorCallback(error) {
    // Other
}
```

Comment: He needs a callback that fires after the user has pressed confirm, but success is called after the position has been determined..

Answer (score 0):

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
//Succes Code
},
function (error) { 
if (error.code == error.PERMISSION_DENIED)
//Code when permission is not granted
});
```

I am not sure, that mobile will respond well to this, but it works on PC.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. when your geolocation code executes, the request goes to browser and then browser asks to user for confirmation. If user accepts, then the request goes forward else it will drop. so you will not get any confirmation whether user clicked on accept button or not. but you will get whether user denied or not by using error **PERMISSION_DENIED**